# Help in identifying the motor

Tags: voltage, motor, dc-motor, motor-controller, arduino-uno

I am total noob in electronics field. I had some broken electonics appliances lying around house so now I am trying to build something out of it. Can you guys please help me with identifying the motor  shown in the picture and what kind of fuse board should i order so i can run it safely at home. It says its a 110v on the motor itself but i am not sure if it takes dc current or ac. I live in canada so can i directly plug it in the socket ?. And can i use arduino with it ?.  Can i use arduino to run the motor as i want program when the motor should run and for how long ?
Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Permanent Magnet DC motor, so you *cannot* directly plug it into the mains. You can tell it is a PMDC motor because it has magnets around the inside of the case (the edges of them are visible in the top photo).

To use this motor with AC you will need a suitably rated bridge rectifier. The appliance you took it out of may have the parts you need.

Comment: A really good way to tell how a motor needs to be driven is to inspect the parts that drive it, before you remove it from the appliance.  While some appliances have gone full electronic, most are still using barely-refined 1930's technologies, so the bits are often out where it's easy to see what's what.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your reply. I'll check if i can still find the appliance from which i took it from. Just in case if i don't can i use a variable ac to dc converter that are being sold on amazon ?

Comment: I'm not sure which 'variable ac to dc converter that are being sold on amazon' you are looking at. Can you provide a link to it or description of the product?

Comment: If I had that motor, I wouldn't trust that "110V" marked on it mean 110 volts. I would start by trying 12 volts DC. If it runs, it should be ok to run it long enough to check the idle current.

Comment: Thanks Charles thats a good point ill try that.  @Bruce i am still trying to find a converter.. i think i should try what charles suggested may be it would work and it is easily available to me too

Comment: It also has a gearbox.